# How do I promisify a GET request with query string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, npm

I make a request successfully with querystring params:

```
// Works
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var request = Promise.promisifyAll(require("request"));

request.get({
    url: 'https://api.angel.co/1/tags/' + encodeURIComponent(friscoLocationTag) + '/startups', 
    qs: {
        access_token: myToken,
        order: 'popularity'
    },
    method: 'GET'
}, function(error, response, body){
    // request success
    console.log(body);
});
```

However when I try to promisfy my request I am failing:

```
// Does Not Work
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var request = Promise.promisifyAll(require("request"));

request.get({
    url: 'https://api.angel.co/1/tags/' + encodeURIComponent(friscoLocationTag) + '/startups', 
    qs: {
        access_token: myToken,
        order: 'popularity'
    },
    method: 'GET'
}).then(function(error, response, body){
    console.log(body);
});
```

This gives the error:

```
}).then(function(error, response, body){
   ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/connorleech/Projects/startup-locator/server/routes.js:36:4)
```

How do I properly promisify my get request using [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The promisified function is called `getAsync`. See [**docs**](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification)

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var request = Promise.promisifyAll(require("request"));

request.getAsync({
    url: 'https://api.angel.co/1/tags/' + encodeURIComponent(friscoLocationTag) + '/startups', 
    qs: {
        access_token: myToken,
        order: 'popularity'
    },
    method: 'GET'
}).then(function(error, response, body){
    console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: ok this works. one thing to note though is that the data comes in as the first parameter, what here is listed as `error`

Comment: @ConnorLeech Right, which is why I mentioned in my answer that there are several nuances to using promisify. Promisify assumes the callback is in the standard format of `(err, res)` whereas request follows the `(error, response, body)` convention. Calling it like that is just not going to work, you'll need to implement a custom promisifier function.

Comment: ok I was looking into how to promisify using bluebird. `getAsync` is what I wanted. Thank you for the answer using request-promise.

Answer (score 5):

There are gotchas trying to promisfy the request module, the issue that you're running into is just one of them. I recommend you to instead look at [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) which is basically what you're trying to do, it is an implementation of the request module using bluebird promises

EDIT:

Install request-promise

```
npm install request-promise --save
```

Then:

```
var request = require('request-promise');

request({
    url: 'https://api.angel.co/1/tags/' + encodeURIComponent(friscoLocationTag) + '/startups', 
    qs: {
        access_token: myToken,
        order: 'popularity'
    },
    method: 'GET'
})
.then(function(body){
  console.log(body)
})
```

Comment: ok please provide a code implementation with this module before I accept

Comment: cool this works. It feels like request-promise is much slower. Have not benchmarked this yet. Thank you

Comment: nvm probz cause i'm on a different internet connection

Comment: I feel like this should be the accepted answer. Promisifying `request` isn't going to work properly without some tinkering.